# Installing Windows 7 on an iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, windows

I have an older version model of an iPad Pro. I need to download an application that requires Windows.

Can I install Windows 7 on my iPad Pro?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is **not** possible to install Windows 7 on an iPad Pro. You'll need a desktop/laptop computer to run Windows.

Unlike generally available consumer computers, where you can choose to install supported operating system of your choice, it is not possible to change the operating system on your iPad (or iOS devices in general).

To install Windows, you'll need access to a PC computer. If you do not have access to a PC, Apple's desktop/laptop computers branded as Mac are capable of running Windows both [natively](https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-assistant/bcmp09f5f773/mac) or in a virtual machine.